# All real numbers $(p,q)$ such that $|\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-p x-q| \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ holds for every $x \in[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, geometry, inequality, contest-math, coordinate-systems

Find all pairs of real numbers $(p, q)$ such that the inequality
$|\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-p x-q| \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ holds for every $x \in[0,1]$

---

Originally I thought to rephrase it in geometric terms, seeing one degree terms I think about equation of a line.

I also have that $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \leq p x+q \leq \sqrt{1-x^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$

I think that a geometric solution might be possible, please help me to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: To get idea make a Taylor development of $ \sqrt{1-x^2}$ it could give you idea of the region where $(p,q)$ are because what you write is really close to a Taylor Lagrange inequality...

Comment: I think a geometric interpretation sounds good - you get a closed shape by taking the interior of the lines $x=0,1$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$. The question is then which lines lie entirely in that shape. Does that help?

Comment: In particular, if you fix an allowable value of $q$ (anything between $\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\frac{3-\sqrt{2}}{2}$), then you get an allowable range of $p$ by varying it between the two values at the tangent of the boundary.

Comment: @EDX I don't really have much familiarity with calculus and I'm looking for an elementary solution, though calculus might help.

Comment: Since the boundary curves are circular arcs, calculus probably isn't necessary

Comment: that sounds nice, I'll try that

Comment: @Ginger where is this problem from?

Comment: it was from a marathon on the site artofproblemsolving.com . So the actual source is not known to me

Comment: It's the optimal order 1 Chebyshev polynomial approximation to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[]0,1}$, so $p,q$ are uniquely determined. The criterion is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Optimal_polynomials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^{2}}-p x-q$, then the condition becomes $$|f(x)| \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$$
Thus, the extrema of $f$ should lie in $\left[ -\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}\right]$. Now, let's see how its extrema look like:
$$f'(x) = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - p = 0 $$ After bringing to a common denominator, numerator should be equal to zero: $$ -x - p\sqrt{1-x^2} = 0 \\[2mm] x = r\sqrt{1-x^2}, \ \ (r=-p) \\[2mm] x^2 = r^2(1-x^2) \\[2mm] (1+r^2)x^2 = r^2 \\[2mm] x_0 = \pm \frac{r}{1+r^2} = \mp\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}$$
However, since $x \ge 0$, we get $$x_0 = -\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} $$
Therefore, $$\begin{align}f(x_0) &= \sqrt{1-\frac{p^2}{1+p^2}} + \frac{p^2}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}-q \\[1mm]&= \frac{1 + p^2}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} -q \\[1mm]&= \sqrt{1+p^2}-q \end{align}$$
Hence, the condition seems to be satisfied for all $p$ and $q$ such that
$$\left| \sqrt{1+p^2} -q \right| \le \frac{\sqrt2 - 1}{2} \tag{1}$$
Also, we need to see the edge cases when $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, which give
$$|f(0)| = \left|1 - q\right| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \tag{2}$$ and $$|f(1)| = \left|-p - q\right| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \tag{3}$$ Finally, combining $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get the final answer.

---

I didn't solve the last three inequalities putting all together, but after graphing I noticed (**but still needs to be justified rigorously** by solving the inequalities) that only one pair satisfies the statement, namely, $$(p,q) = \left(-1, \frac{\sqrt 2 + 1}{2}\right)$$

---

[image]

---

Below is the graph with those $p$ and $q$:

[image]

Comment: You should also bring in the condition when $|f(x)|$ achieves its bounds when $x=0,x=1$  ie an additional condition $|f(0)|,|f(1)| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thanks, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Remark: @VIVID gave a nice solution. I rewrote it in elementary way (without using derivative, extrema). Note that **while we used calculus to motivate our solution, we do not need to include any
calculus in the solution!**

Letting $x = 0$, we have $|1 - q| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ or
$$1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \le q \le 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}. \tag{1}$$

Letting $x = 1$, we have $|-p - q| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ or
$$-p - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \le q \le -p + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), we know that $p < 0$ (reason: if $p\ge 0$ then $-p + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} < 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$).

Since $-\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} \in [0, 1]$, by letting $x = -\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}$,
we have $|\sqrt{p^2+1} - q| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ or
$$\sqrt{p^2+1} - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \le q \le \sqrt{p^2 + 1} + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}. \tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), since $\sqrt{p^2 + 1} > -p$, we have
$$\sqrt{p^2+1} - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \le -p + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$$
that is
$\sqrt{p^2 + 1} + p - \sqrt{2} + 1 \le 0$ or
$\frac{(p^2+1) - 2}{\sqrt{p^2+1} + \sqrt{2}}  + (p+1) \le 0$ or
$\frac{(p -  1 + \sqrt{p^2+1} + \sqrt{2})(p+1)}{\sqrt{p^2+1} + \sqrt{2}} \le 0$ which results in
$p \le -1$.

From (1) and (3), since $1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \le \sqrt{p^2 + 1} + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$, we have
$$\sqrt{p^2+1} - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \le 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$$
that is $p^2 \le 1$. Thus, we have $p = -1$.

From (1) and (3), we have $q = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$.

Finally, when $p = -1, q = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$, it is easy to prove that $|\sqrt{1-x^2} + x - 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}| \le \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}, \forall x \in [0, 1]$
that is $1\le \sqrt{1-x^2} + x \le \sqrt{2}, \forall x\in [0, 1]$.

Thus, $p = -1, q = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ is the only one pair satisfies the statement.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and drew an example in Geogebra. Let $\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$. It was clearly chosen specially, since it looks like almost no choices of $q$ (labelled $E$ in the plot) allow *any* solutions.

[image: Plot of the region bounded by the lines in the question, showing an unallowed value of p and q]

With that in mind, I'll consider a *necessary* condition for there to be any solutions $p$ for a given value of $q$.

> Condition: The line joining $(0,q)$ to $(1,\alpha)$ must not cross the lower circle.

When does that happen? Well, experimenting suggests it never happens, and the chord is tangent when $q=1+\alpha$. So maybe we try to prove that the line $AB$ is tangent to the circle $DC$.

The line $AB$ has equation $y=1+\alpha - x$. Does this intersect the circle $DC$? That is equivalent to asking for solutions of $1+\alpha-x = \sqrt{1-x^2} - \alpha$, or:

\begin{align}
1-x^2 &= (1+2\alpha-x)^2 \\
&= (\sqrt{2}-x)^2 \\
&= 2-2\sqrt{2}x + x^2 \\
2x^2 - 2\sqrt{2} x + 1 &= 0 \\
(\sqrt{2}x - 1)^2 &= 0.
\end{align}

So we have a point of tangency. Clearly, therefore, if $q < 1+\alpha$ then there is no value of $p$ such that the line is contained in the figure $ABCD$. This means the only solution is $(-1, 1+\alpha)$.